# JSP form tag action attribute URI Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, uri

I got controller like this

```
   @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/pizza")
    public class PizzaController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewPizzas(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pizzas",
                pizzaService.getAllPizzas());
        return "pizzas";
    }
     @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String create() {
            return "newpizza";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addnew", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addNewPizza(@ModelAttribute Pizza newPizza) {
            pizzaService.addPizza(newPizza);
            return "redirect:";
        }

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String edit(@RequestParam("pizzaid") Long id, 
                Model model) {
            if (id<=0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("ID<0");
            Pizza pizza = pizzaService.getPizzaById(id);
            if (pizza == null) 
                throw new NotFoundPizzaException("Pizza id" + id + " not found" );
            model.addAttribute("pizza", pizza);
            return "newpizza";
        }
    }
```

and JSP's:pizzas.jsp

```
    <body>
        <table border="1">
           ......................
                        <form method="get" action="edit" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="pizzaid" value="${pizza.id}" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
                        </form>        

        </table>
        <a href="create"> Create new pizza </a> <br/>
    </body>
```

and newpizza.jsp

```
<body>
        <form action="addnew" method="post">
                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${pizza.id}"/>
            Name : <input type="text" name="name" value="${pizza.name}"/></br>
            Type : <input type="text" name="type" value="${pizza.type}"/></br>
            Price : <input type="text" name="price" value="${pizza.price}"/></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/></br>
        </form>
    </body>
```

And this works fine, untill I try to change URI's in my Controller, for example like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnew/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and in form tag:

```
<form action="addnew/add" method="post">
<form action="edit/add" method="get">
```

I get `HTTP Status 404`. I have a question: how should I use `action` attribute, to get the opportunity to request mapings like this `@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/add"`...

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`? Where did you get that from?

Comment: @MrLister, my mistake. New to jsp stuff.

Comment: I'm just curious where you got that from. Some HTML elements have start and end tags, some have only start tags. There are no circumstances where just an end tag by itself is OK! So I was wondering; especially because I see that more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your most likely issue is that in the way you currently use your `action` attribute it is treated as relative path, and it gets added to the current url. Depending on the current url in the browser they might or might not work.

To avoid this, use absolute paths in the `action` attribute, e.g

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pizza/addnew/add" method="post">
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pizza/edit/add" method="get">
```